# How to access my local jupyter notebooks over internet

Tags: ipad, jupyter-notebook

I am new to jupyter, I have jupyter running locally on "http://localhost:8888".

I have the *.ipynb files stored locally. I would like ot access them on my ipad  on the go as well. Is there a possibility for that, if so can any one guide on how it can be accomplished.Can we access local notebooks over the internet via some cloud services ?

PS : I tried installing Juno on my ipad, but still wondering how to access my local files (which are on my desktop) in my ipad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently struggling with the same issue.

The answer to you question heavily depends on whether you'd be the only user accessing the Jupyter server or not. If the former is the case (you as the only user) you may refer to materials from the official Jupyter Notebook documentation [here](http://%20https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html). On the same page, for multi-user collaboration [JupyterHub](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is recommended. Besides the Jupter configuration itself, you have to alter [the firewall settings](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#firewall-setup) on your machine and probably forward ports on your router (but the official tutorial says nothing about that).